# Validating before invoking ShowDialog

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, showdialog

I'm working with two forms where I have to validate inputs in the first form before I can switch to the 2nd form.

My Code in the first form is as follows:

```
private void btnSignIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetInputs();
        IsValidata();
        de.Text = string.Format("Hello! {0} {1} {2}{3} {4} {5})",
          Fname, Lname, "(U", Unum1, "-", Unum2);
        this.Hide();
        de.ShowDialog();
    }
```

IsValidata() is a series of validations where it checks if the input is present and if it is a string.

I tried putting these inside the curly braces however validation would not work:

```
  de.Text = string.Format("Hello! {0} {1} {2}{3} {4} {5})",
          Fname, Lname, "(U", Unum1, "-", Unum2);
        this.Hide();
        de.ShowDialog();
```

The only way I'm able to load form2 is by taking out the curly braces but the logic is not correct and it's not exactly validating my inputs. What am I missing?

Comment: Hi, can you please show the code for the `IsValidata()` method?  If we assume that this returns a `bool`, indicating whether or not we are "valid", you currently don't do anything with that.  Likely missing an `if` that only shows the second form if `IsValidata()` returns `true`.

Comment: I've tried putting if (IsValidData()) and within it is the de.Text = ....de.ShowDialog() but when I did that, the button to display the 2nd form would not work. It simply stays in form1.

Comment: But that's what you want, right?  If the data is not valid, then don't show form 2.  What type of behaviour are you actually wanting?

Comment: I'm trying to have a returned MessageBox asking the user to correct the error. Say for instance, if there's no input, it should prompt the use to input a required value. If the user inputs a digit rather than a string, it will prompt the user to input only characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing some control flow logic in your event handler.

Let's assume that you want to simply show a message box to the user if the input is invalid.  Otherwise, if the input is valid, display the second form.

```
private void btnSignIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GetInputs();
    if (IsValidata())
    {
        de.Text = string.Format("Hello! {0} {1} {2}{3} {4} {5})",
            Fname, Lname, "(U", Unum1, "-", Unum2);
        this.Hide();
        de.ShowDialog();
    }
    else
    { 
        // Show a message box, with an OK button only
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Input", "Invalid Input", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
    }
}
```

In the example above, we:

- Get the input
- Check if the data is valid
- If the data **is** valid, show the new form
- If the data **is not** valid, we display a message to the user

If you want to display a message based on the *results of the validation* (i.e. if the user input digits only instead of a string), you'll need to add that logic in, and construct the message that you want to display.

**Update:**

Ok, so you actually want the validation routine to return the **type** of validation that has failed (if any fail).

So let's define a new type that the validation method can return:

```
public class ValidationResult 
{
    public bool IsValid { get; set; }
    public string UserMessage { get; set; }
}
```

Now we can update the validation method:

```
private ValidationResult IsValidata()
{
    //validate the First Name textbox
    if (!IsPresent(txtFirst, "First Name"))
    {
        return new ValidationResult { 
            IsValid = false, 
            UserMessage = "Please enter a First Name"
        };
    }

    // rest of valiation rules here,
    // setting the UserMessage as appropriate

    // If no validation checks fail, then we are valid
    return new ValidationResult { IsValid = true };
}
```

Now your event handler can use the results:

```
private void btnSignIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GetInputs();
    var validationResult = IsValidata();
    if (validationResult.IsValid)
    {
        de.Text = string.Format("Hello! {0} {1} {2}{3} {4} {5})",
            Fname, Lname, "(U", Unum1, "-", Unum2);
        this.Hide();
        de.ShowDialog();
    }
    else
    { 
        // Show a message box, with an OK button only
        MessageBox.Show(validationResult.UserMessage, "Invalid Input", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: I just want to be sure I understand this. I have created separate methods for each bool condition in IsValidData() with its respective message if the error if invoked. Is this what you meant or would I have to add a separate message within the method where login values are inputted and validated?

Comment: The answer has been updated to cover the additional requirements that you have.  Note that the question wasn't very clear as to what you wanted to achieve.  It's always a good idea to be as thorough as you can with questions here.

Comment: Thank you so much. I understand it now. I've been attempting to implement the validation method as you have show however, looking at your updated response, I see I'm missing the accessor and an instance of a validation result.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code for my Valid data:

```
private bool IsValidata()
{

            //validate the First Name textbox
            if (!IsPresent(txtFirst, "First Name"))
            {
                return false;
            }
            if (!StringValidator(Fname))
            {
                return false;
            }           

            //validate the Last Name textbox
            if (!IsPresent(txtLast, "Last Name"))
            {
                return false;
            }
            if (!StringValidator(Lname))
            {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
}
```